# How to setup deployments in Azure so that they use different databases depending on the environment?

Tags: database, azure

You can easily swap two deployments between staging and production environment in the Azure Management Portal by swapping their VIP. When working on a staging version of the services we want to use a staging database as well so we don't risk clobbering actual customer data. However, after swapping staging and production services the now-production (and formerly staging) deployment should obviously work on the production database.

So essentially the database to use would depend on whether the instance runs in the *Staging* or *Production* environment. Is there a good way of achieving that? Relying on the VIP and hard-coding the database switching based on that is probably not the best idea, I guess.

Comment: Both valid answers below. Staging in Azure isn't really a test environment as such, only a way to ensure everything is running before production and quick swap back if something fails. Use on site or a seperate subscription.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My recommendation would be to stop using the "staging slot" of a service for the function you used a traditional "staging environment" for. When I'm speaking to folks about Windows Azure, I strongly recommend they use the staging slots only to smoke test a new deployment before it goes live. If they want a more protracted sort of testing, the kind many of us are used to having on-premises, then use a separate service and possibly even a separate subscription (the later is great if you want cost transparency).

All this said, your only real options are to have a second service configuration that is specific for production that you update to before you execute the VIP swap, or you write some code that allows the service to detect which slot it's in and pull the appropriate of two configuration settings.

However, as I outlined in the first paragraph, I think there's a better way to do things. :)

Comment: +1 "Staging slots" should not be used for extended testing.  If an application uses SSL, there can be some things that aren't testable in the "staging slot" because the staging url makes the SSL cert invalid.

Answer (score 6):

In a recent release of Azure Websites, the story here has changed.  You may now specify that any app setting or connection string is a "slot setting", pinning it to the particular slot.  To solve your issue, you would simply set the connection string(s) in each slot and take care to check 'Slot Setting'.

I'm less clear if this is an advisable approach now. Database schema migration and rollback aren't baked in, and I'm unsure how to handle that correctly. Also only app settings and connection strings work this way, so, for example, system.net.mail settings cannot be pinned to a slot.  For that, you'd need to change code to get mail server info, etc. from app settings or else use some other approach.

Comment: I think the miss-sell here is the concept of just swapping back if something doesn't work right. At best it's running rollback scripts, and at worst it's restore of a database. What you seem to be getting from slots is a all-at-once update of all your websites and webjobs. If you have a lot of instances, this could be a significant deployment time. Course, if you don't have DB changes then it's easy...but how often does that happen?

Answer (score 2):

Re: "When working on a staging version of the services we want to use a staging database as well so we don't risk clobbering actual customer data." There is not a built-in way to do this.

If you wish to test without risk to production data, consider doing this testing in another Azure account - one that doesn't even have access to the production database. Then, when you think the system is tested and ready to go live, only then bring it up into the staging slot next to your production instance for a final smoke test.

I can imagine scenarios where you'd also want to a run through a few scenarios on the staging instance before doing a VIP Swap, but don't want to pollute production data. For this, many companies use special accounts - data associated with these accounts is known (or marked somehow) to be not from real customers so can be skipped in reporting and billing and such.

Re: "Relying on the VIP and hard-coding the database switching based on that is probably not the best idea, I guess." If by hard-coding, you mean reading it from a config file, that is probably not a bad idea, if you use an approach as mentioned above. I have heard of some folks going with a "figure out if we are in a staging slot and do something different in the code" approach, but I rather recommend what I described above.